# Is there a simple way to find out lowest value from JSON without doing de-serialization?

Tags: c#, json, min

I have below JSON output from API. I want to find out lowest value among all elements.

JSON data:

```
{
  "prices": [   
    {
      "frequency": "daily",
      "date": "2020-05-05",
      "intraperiod": false,
      "open": 295.06,
      "high": 301.0,
      "low": 294.46,
      "close": 297.56
    },
    {
      "frequency": "daily",
      "date": "2020-05-04",
      "intraperiod": false,
      "open": 289.17,
      "high": 293.69,
      "low": 112.1,
      "close": 293.16
    },
    {
      "frequency": "daily",
      "date": "2020-05-01",
      "intraperiod": false,
      "open": 286.25,
      "high": 299.0,
      "low": 222,
      "close": 289.07
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to compare all values among JSON element and display lowest value =  `"low": 112.1` and its own high value. `"high": 293.69,`

I tried like below using jQuery, but how can I do it in C#?

```
function get(arr, prop) {
    var min;
    for (var i=0 ; i<arr.length ; i++) {
        if (min== null || parseInt(arr[i][prop]) > parseInt(min[prop]))
            min= arr[i];
    }
    return min;
}

var min = get(arr, "low");
console.log(min.high);
```

Comment: No, there is no simple way to do this without deserializing it, at least into some form of object structure?

Comment: ohh i see hmm could you please help me with sample code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq` for that, parse your JSON to [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm), then get all properties with `low` name, find the property with lowest value and get the `high` value at the same level

```cs
var json = JObject.Parse(jsonString);

var properties = json.DescendantsAndSelf()
    .OfType<JProperty>()
    .Where(p => p.Name == "low");

 var lowProperty = properties
     .Aggregate((p1, p2) => p1.Value.Value<double>() < p2.Value.Value<double>() ? p1 : p2);

var highProperty = (lowProperty?.Parent as JObject)?.Property("high");
Console.WriteLine(lowProperty);
Console.WriteLine(highProperty);
```

It gives you

```
"low": 112.1
"high": 293.69
```

Answer (score 2):

De-serializing it would be the way to go

you can de-serialize it into an object and do the calculations you want

```
    // <auto-generated />
//
// To parse this JSON data, add NuGet 'Newtonsoft.Json' then do:
//
//    using QuickType;
//
//    var priceData = PriceData.FromJson(jsonString);

namespace QuickType
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using System.Globalization;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

    public partial class PriceData
    {
        [JsonProperty("prices")]
        public List<Price> Prices { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Price
    {
        [JsonProperty("frequency")]
        public string Frequency { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("date")]
        public DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("intraperiod")]
        public bool Intraperiod { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("open")]
        public double Open { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("high")]
        public double High { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("low")]
        public double Low { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("close")]
        public double Close { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class PriceData
    {
        public static PriceData FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PriceData>(json, QuickType.Converter.Settings);
    }

    public static class Serialize
    {
        public static string ToJson(this PriceData self) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, QuickType.Converter.Settings);
    }

    internal static class Converter
    {
        public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
            Converters =
            {
                new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
            },
        };
    }
}
```

you can use [Quciktype](https://app.quicktype.io/) to get POCO class from the json (The above code is from generated from that)

Then use

```
var data = PriceData.FromJson(json_string);
var min = data.Select(x=>x.Low).Min();
// There may be multiple Price objects with the same low, I will use the first one
min_object = data.Where(x=>x.Low == min).First()
var high_value_of_min_object = min_object.High;
```

You may want to decide what element you are looking for
P.S I have not tested the code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex.

```
var pattern = "\"high\": ([0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?)";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(json, pattern);

var max = double.MinValue;
foreach (Match m in matches) {
    var val = Convert.ToDouble(m.Groups[1].Value);
    if (max < val) {
        max = val;
    }           
}
```

Same for low value.

Answer (score 1):

You could create classes to represent your JSON using a tool like [quicktype.io](https://quicktype.io/csharp/):

```
public partial class Temperatures
{
    [JsonProperty("prices")]
    public List<Price> Prices { get; set; }
}

public partial class Price
{
    [JsonProperty("frequency")]
    public string Frequency { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("date")]
    public DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("intraperiod")]
    public bool Intraperiod { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("open")]
    public double Open { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("high")]
    public double High { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("low")]
    public double Low { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("close")]
    public double Close { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize your json using [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json), and use [`MinBy`](https://morelinq.github.io/1.x/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_MinBy__2_1.htm) from [MoreLinq](https://morelinq.github.io/1.x/ref/api/html/N_MoreLinq.htm) to get the minimum prices by `Low`. `MinBy` will return a `IEnumerable<Price>`, so we can iterate each min price and print the `Low` and `High` properties:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using MoreLinq;

...

var deserializedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Temperatures>(json);

var minPrices = deserializedJson.Prices.MinBy(price => price.Low);

foreach (var price in minPrices)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Min = {price.Low}, High = {price.High}");
}
```

**Output:**

```
Min = 112.1, High = 293.69
```

Full demo on [dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/L7l6lM)